# Determine the principal strain of a 2x2 matrix

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-equations

For a 2D problem the strain matrix is given by

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\varepsilon_{xx} & \varepsilon_{xy} \\
\varepsilon_{xy} & \varepsilon_{yy} \\
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0.1 \\
0.1 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Determine the principal strains

**Solution**:

First the eigenvalues have to be computed:

\begin{align}
\det{\textbf{A} - \lambda \mathbb{I}} &= \det \begin{bmatrix}
- \lambda & 0.1 \\
0.1 & -\lambda
\end{bmatrix}
= \lambda^2 - 0.1^2 = 0\\
\lambda_{1,2} &= \pm 0.1
\end{align}

Then the first eignevector $\vec{v}_1$ is determined by

\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix}-0.1 & 0.1 \\ 0.1 & -0.1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix} &=
\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} \\
-0.1x + 0.1y &= 0 \label{eq1} \tag{1}\\
\vec{v}_1 & = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1^2 + 1^2}} \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} \label{eq2} \tag{2}
\end{align}

and the second eigenvector is given by

$$
\vec{v}_2
\begin{pmatrix} -1/\sqrt{2} \\ 1/\sqrt{2} \end{pmatrix}
$$

**My question**

This is certainly a basic algebra question, but how to you get from (1) to (2)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have $0.1y-0.1x=0\implies x=y$. The eigenvector $\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}x\\x\end{bmatrix},x\in\Bbb R-\{0\}$. So one possibility for the eigenvector is when $x=1/\sqrt2$, that is,$\begin{bmatrix}1/\sqrt2\\1/\sqrt2\end{bmatrix}=\frac1{\sqrt2}\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Shubham Johri. Now where does the $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1^2+1^2}}$ come from?

Comment: Note that if $\bf v$ is an eigenvector of $A$ corresponding to eigenvalue $\lambda$, $k\bf v$$(k\ne0)$ is also an eigenvector of $A$ corresponding to the same eigenvalue. This is because $A\mathbf v=\lambda\mathbf v\implies A(k\mathbf v)=\lambda(k\mathbf v)$.

Comment: Take $x=1$ to get the eigenvector $\mathbf v=(1,1)^T$. The norm of $\mathbf v$ is $\|\mathbf v\|=\sqrt{1^2+1^2}$, so if you divide $\bf v$ by $\|\mathbf v\|=\sqrt2$, you will get the unit vector $\frac1{\sqrt2}\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\end{bmatrix}$ which is also an eigenvector corresponding to the same eigenvalue.